# How do I fix the error "makeappx.exe - System Error"?

Tags: windows

The error reads:
The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Information:
I was trying to run WSAppBak on Windows 8.1.

This sentence was added due to the weird requirements of question length.